# showing a function is a measure

Tags: real-analysis

If $\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n$ are measures on $(X,M)$ and $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in[0,\infty)$, then $\sum_{1}^{n}a_j \mu_j$ is a measure on $(X,M)$

I believe we first need to prove that if $\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n$ are measures on $(X,M)$ then we need to show that $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ and then construct a sequence of disjoint sets using the function they provided in the problem and show that it is in $M$ then we can conclude it is a measure on $(X,M)$?

I want to do this on my own but I could use some hints just want to know if I am understanding what the problem is asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\nu=\sum_{j=1}^na_j\mu_j$ and $(A_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of disjoints sets of $M$. You have to show:

1. $\nu(\emptyset)=0$
2. $\nu(\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty}A_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\nu(A_i)$

Comment: For the 1, can we say that since $\mu$ is already a measure on $(X,M)$ and $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in [0,\infty)$ then we must have the case that $v(\emptyset) = 0$?

Comment: As $\mu_j$ is a measure for all $j$, we have $\mu_j(\emptyset)=0$ for all $j$. It follows that $\nu(\emptyset)=0$.

Comment: Since, $v(\emptyset) = \sum_{1}^{n}a_j\mu_j(\emptyset) = \sum_{1}^{n}a_j0 = 0$?